# Is it possible to disallow self-recursion?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the rule:

```
expression
   : //...
   | expression (relative_operator expression)+
   | //...
   ;
```

Ideally, when I put in `1=1=1`, it will produce the `expression(1, =, 1, =, 1)` tree. However, in reality it produces `expression(1, =, expression(1, =, 1))`. This is because it prefers to parse recursively rather than in a line. Is it possible to explicitly tell a rule that it either can't recurse on itself, or it should prefer to obey the `+`/`*` before trying to recurse on itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to explicitly tell a rule that it either can't recurse on itself, or it should prefer to obey the +/* before trying to recurse on itself?

No, you will have to rewrite your grammar like this:

```antlr
expr
 : add
 ;

add
 : mult ( ( '+' | '-' ) mult )*
 ;

mult
 : unary ( ( '*' | '/' ) unary )*
 ;

unary
 : '-'? atom
 ;

atom
 : '(' expr ')'
 | NUMBER
 | VARIABLE
 ;
```

which will parse input like `1 + 2 + 3 * 4 * 5 / 6` into the following tree:

[image]